# Is it possible to export multiple components from one single file in vue?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vuetify.js, cdn, vuetifyjs3

I've made a project with vue3 + vuetify without node.
I'm a beginner in vue and before I've worked with react, where I did this but I'm not being able to do the same here in vue.

An example to why I would want to have multiple components in same file is to make a single file Icons.vue and there contain multiple SVG, like in the example of how I tried to do it:

```
<script>
export const AccountIcon = {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
          <title>AccountIcon</title>
          <path d="M12,4A4,4 0 0,1 16,8A4,4 0 0,1 12,12A4,4 0 0,1 8,8A4,4 0 0,1 12,4M12,14C16.42,14 20,15.79 20,18V20H4V18C4,15.79 7.58,14 12,14Z" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    );
  },
};

export const AccountIconTest2 = {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
          <title>AccountIconTest2</title>
          <path d="M12,4A4,4 0 0,1 16,8A4,4 0 0,1 12,12A4,4 0 0,1 8,8A4,4 0 0,1 12,4M12,14C16.42,14 20,15.79 20,18V20H4V18C4,15.79 7.58,14 12,14Z" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    );
  },
};
</script>
```

Then the use of it:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-icon>
      <AccountIcon />
    </v-icon>
    <v-icon>
      <AccountIconTest2 />
    </v-icon>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { AccountIcon, AccountIconTest2 } from "./components/icons.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    AccountIcon,
    AccountIconTest2,
  },
};
</script>
```

That's how I think it should be written but I've seen many ways to do it on different forums, but I did not get any of them work.
But obviously this doesn't work, is there any way to make something like this?

Comment: You shouldn't with `<script>` or .vue files, that's for Single File Components, expecting one component only.  When writing [render functions](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html) (like you are) you can export multiple from a single .js or .jsx file

Comment: The way you're trying to export and import the components **is not** correct. In cdn you can do like ```<script>const AccountIcon = { render() { return (..) } }</script>```